# Java library for the use of Skype API

Tags: java, api, skype

Can anyone suggest any java library to use Skype public API?
I have not found Skype4Java or JSkype libraries.

Comment: I Googled **skype api java** and found a ton of libraries. Why can't you use them?

Comment: I also Googled. All that I have found is obsolete. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Found this: https://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/java/index.html

Comment: It costs $5.00, which is basically free. I don't work with Skype, so I can't help you any more than that.

Comment: https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found skype4java. Yesterday download link was not available, so I thought that the library is not supported. Now everything is fine.
 
[Link for download](http://cvs.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/skype.tar.gz?view=tar)
[Useful article](http://half-wit4u.blogspot.com/2011/05/skype-using-java-api-skype4java.html)

Thank you all