# Add contact/friend in skype using api in Java

Tags: java, api, skype, skype4java

I want to add new contact to a skype account using java with skype api.
Is there any java package available to use for the objective?
Also if there is any sample code available for it please share the link
Thanks in advance

Comment: may be you are looking for this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477677/java-library-for-the-use-of-skype-api)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void sendFriendRequest(String skypeId) throws SkypeException {
    Skype.getContactList().addFriend(skypeId, "Confirmation message here, etc! :D");
}
```

it should be on line 198 on - https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/skype/ContactList.java
Just realize that its a different Skype-API. Sorry.